# Ambiguous [rule] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [rule](/questions/tagged/rule) seems to be ambiguous, the excerpt itself contains ambiguous explanation:

> Rule might refer to various things: business rules, JUnit rules, a
>   rule of thumb, rules engines

Is there a need for this tag? What should be done?

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't seem to be a need for it...

Burninate!

[image]

Comment: +1 added the [tag:burninate-request] tag. :D